# confused about Passing by reference and passing by value in c#

Tags: c#, reference, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

i am a new programmer here. I have the following code. I passed the object by value, but when i printed the results, i got this

```
elf attacked orc for 20 damage!
Current Health for orc is 80
elf attacked orc for 20 damage!
Current Health for orc is 80
```

this got me confused about passing by reference because I did not expect the health in the main to be 80 since i passed the object by value. Can someone explain how the result for health in the program main function was 80 instead of 100?

```
//MAIN class
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace passingTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Enemy Objects
            Enemy elf = new Enemy("elf", 100, 1, 20);
            Enemy orc = new Enemy("orc", 100, 1, 20);
            elf.Attack(orc);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} attacked {1} for {2} damage!", elf.Nm, orc.Nm, elf.Wpn);
            Console.WriteLine("Current Health for {0} is {1}", orc.Nm, orc.Hlth);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}

// Enemy Class

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace passingTest
{
    class Enemy
    {
        // variables
        string nm = "";
        int hlth = 0;
        int lvl = 0;
        int wpn = 0;

        public string Nm
        {
            get { return nm; }
            set { nm = value; }
        }
        public int Wpn
        {
            get { return wpn; }
            set { wpn = value; }
        }
        public int Hlth
        {
            get { return hlth; }
            set { hlth = value; }
        }
        public Enemy(string name, int health, int level, int weapon)
        {
            nm = name;
            hlth = health;
            lvl = level;
            wpn = weapon;
        }
        public void Attack(Enemy rival){
            rival.hlth -= this.wpn;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} attacked {1} for {2} damage!", this.nm, rival.nm, this.wpn);
            Console.WriteLine("Current Health for {0} is {1}", rival.nm, rival.hlth);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not so clear what confuses you, in the attack method the orc health damage and then you just print it again on the main

Comment: If you are confused why not just do a C# MSDN google search on `ref vs value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#/.NET, whether an object is passed by reference or by value is determined by the type of the object.  If the object is a reference type (i.e. it is declared with `class`), it is passed by reference.  If the object is a value type (i.e. it is declared with `struct`) it is passed by value.

If you change the declaration of Enemy to

```
struct Enemy
```

you will see pass-by-value semantics.

Answer (score 1):

In C# Classes are considered reference types. A reference type is a type which has as its value a reference to the appropriate data rather than the data itself. For instance, consider the following code:

Here;s a link with more information on the subject: http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html